# Mesos: Failed to detect master

Tags: apache-zookeeper, iptables, mesos

Greeting,

i've set up a mesos master node (on one vm) and a slave node (on another vm).
Applying the command: MASTER=$(mesos-resolve `cat /etc/mesos/zk`)

It runs through and i get the following message:

```
I1229 12:05:31.943322  1524 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(1)@10.155.208.82:42540) connected to ZooKeeper
I1229 12:05:31.943480  1524 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I1229 12:05:31.943547  1524 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
Failed to detect master from 'zk://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181/mesos' within 5secs
```

I tried to use

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 5050 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 2181 -j ACCEPT
```

however I still get the "Failed to detect master from..." message. What is triggering this error message? How and where can a more detailed error-log be obtained? Thanks in advance for any hints and with best regards

Comment: Have you verified that ZooKeeper is actually running?